# making hat over a character BOLD in text mode

Tags: xetex

Using the following method, I can place a hat symbol over any character in text mode.

```
\^{}
```

How can I render the hat in bold?

**UPDATE:**

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}


\setsansfont[
BoldFont={Avenir Next LT Pro Bold},
ItalicFont={Avenir Next LT Pro Italic},
BoldItalicFont={Avenir Next LT Pro Bold Italic}
]{Avenir Next LT Pro}

\begin{document}
%-----------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}
    \textbf{\^{\mdseries δ}}
\end{frame}
%-----------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you *really* need this

```
\textbf{\^{\mdseries o}}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't have any effect on the hat symbol.

Comment: @Shahzad it should, see image I just added

Comment: Its working when the document class is 'article' (I haven't tested on others) but its not working under beamer document class.

Comment: @Shahzad You did not provide a test file:-) Is there a bold font for the font family you are using?

Comment: I have provided the test file but I believe its xunicode package which is posing the problem. I need to use this package so is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @Shahzad why do you need xunicode or xltxextra, you should only really need fontspec, really.

Answer (score 1):

First excuse: This solution works fine with LaTeX, not XeTeX.

I take full responsibility for suggesting this horrible kludge... solely due to the fact that the answer by David Carlisle seems not to work, as reported by Shahzad. Why? Maybe some of the collections are not installed. Maybe font detection is broken, `fc-cache` behaves like a brat etc. Hard to guess.

If your audience is not so picky, you can superimpose things with a slight shift in order to fake boldness. This is horrible, this is bad practice, but if nothing else works *or* you are a purist who does not want to load any custom packages, this little Frankenstein is for you. One-use only.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{default}

\newlength\my
\settowidth{\my}{a} % Should be 5pt for a, might differ for other letters

\newlength\tinyadj
\newlength\adjplus
\newlength\adjminus
\setlength{\tinyadj}{0.1\my}
\setlength{\adjplus}{1.05\my}
\setlength{\adjminus}{0.9\my}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
H\^{\kern-\adjplus\^a}t and H\^at

Extremely nasty: H\kern-\tinyadj\^{\kern-\adjplus\^{\kern-\adjminus\^a}}t
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Quick and dirty solution]

Oh my. Resort to this only if **no** other solution remedies the predicament. And sorry for not being able to do this in XeTeX... maybe someone wants to reproduce this exercise in LaTeX. Maybe just someone needs a re-e-eally bold accent that does not exist in any available font.

Comment: “Andreï, why on Earth would you post a bad practice? Wanna get downvoted?” — “To show everyone how bad it is, but sometimes there is not enought time. Some things have to be done urgently, and this is the most intuitive thing one can concoct in 5 minutes.”